# Cronjob database replace not executing

Tags: mysql, database, cron

I'm trying to setup cronjob to replace database on Demo site every so often (testing with 10 minutes)
Running VPS with Centmin Nginx on CentOS

Crontab gets created and saved fine using *`crontab -e`* but it does not execute.
Even running cron command in Shell does not do it.

Occasionally I'd get this error message entering command manually:

> "ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 43: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   "

Here is the cron:

```
*/10 * * * * mysql -uroot -pMYPASSWORD DBNAME < /home/nginx/domains/mysite.com/private/db/DBNAME.sql
```

I exported the databse via PhpMyAdmin and uploaded to *`/home/nginx/domains/mysite.com/private/db/`* folder
Is there certain way database needs to be saved?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Resolved by creating databse in Shell via mysqldump now it's working.

Comment: Is `DBNAME.sql` executable? This question should be on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do the first lines of the DBNAME.sql script drop or purge your database?  If not, then your issue is probably the fact that it's trying to load data into the database that is causing primary key issues.  Also, pipe the output to a log file so that you can see what is going on - all output is otherwise going to a mailbox that you might not have access to.

Comment: Check you sql . The error indicates a primary key violation with id=3

Comment: Your cron looks ok...the problems is with your sql file

Comment: Yes it was with database, I used mysqldump command to create backup and cron is now working. Thanks all :)